# Html.fromHtml on Nougat doesn't call custom HtmlHandler

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, fromhtml

I have a custom `TextView`, to show html text. For pre-Nougat devices it works. As you already know on Nougat, fromHtml is deprecated and it needs a flag..so my code is like this

```
 Spannable s = getRichText(text);
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
     super.setText(Html.fromHtml(s.toString(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT, this, new HtmlHandler(getContext())), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
 } else {
     super.setText(Html.fromHtml(s.toString(), this, new HtmlHandler(getContext())), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
 }
```

The problem it that, the `HtmlHandler` class is never get called. (I have already tried all the flags).
On `HtmlHandler` I handle tags and styles, eg `background-color`, `color` et cetera. I have implemented to get colors from `rgb`, `rgba`, `hls` etc. But on Nougat it accepts only colors with hex, because on Nougat, `fromHTML` can "read" colors and show them. Why is this happening? How can I keep my way for the colors? If you didn't understand something, or need more details, let me know.

The html I use for testing is

```
<p><strong>Server</strong><u> message</u><strong><u>!!!</strong></u> <span style="background-color: rgb(255,0,0);">Not working on Nugat</span></p>
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide a sample of the HTML, plus an indication of what out of that is not being routed to your `TagHandler` (where it used to pre-7.0)? For example, `Html` has supported `<font color="...">` for quite some time. I see that 7.1 (and presumably 7.0) now handles `<span>` tags, whereas it did not do so before -- is that where your problem lies?

Comment: I edit the question. The problem isn't the `span`. Because It doesn't work neither with `div` nor with `p`. The problem is that my  `HtmlHandler` class never gets called. That's the weird part

Comment: In my TagHandler I check for `ol`, `ul`, `strike`, `code`, `span`, `div` and for css styles for `background-color`, `color` and for fontawesome, and non of them is working on Nougat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Html.fromHtml()` will only invoke your `TagHandler` for HTML tags that `fromHtml()` does not recognize. In your sample HTML, you have:

- `<p>`
- `<strong>`
- `<u>`
- `<span>`

and in your first comment, you also mention `div`.

Of those, `fromHtml()` has handled `<p>`, `<strong>`, and `<u>` since [at least 2010](https://commonsware.com/blog/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html), if not earlier. `fromHtml()` in Android 6.0 also handles `<div>` (see lines 488-489 in [the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-6.0.1_r70/core/java/android/text/Html.java)), and I forget how back that support goes. Your `TagHandler` would not be called for any of these tags, and that behavior is not especially new.

Android 7.0 added support for `<span>` (see lines 804-805 from [the 7.1 source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-7.1.0_r4/core/java/android/text/Html.java)), and so code that expected a `TagHandler` to be invoked for `<span>` would behave differently between Android 7.0 and previous versions.

In general, the list of supported tags is undocumented. Google is welcome to change the roster of supported tags at any point.

Your options are:

- Live with it
- Grab the source to some `Html.java` that you like, refactor it into your own package, and use that copy, modifying it as you see fit
- Find some other HTML-to-`Spannable` source code that you like better

Comment: Ok I got it. I'll see what I can do. Thank you very much!